# Convert emojis into Unicode

Tags: ios, unicode, cross-platform, chat, emoji

I develop chatting application in cross platform. I sent emojis from iphone to iphone working properly. but when i try to sent to android from iphone not properly display. Android library understand Unicode like **U+1F604**. While i convert emojis  into Unicode it return result like **\ud83d\ude04**. I want result like 1F604.

**Code**

```
NSData *data = [_txtMessage.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thank You in Advance. :)

Comment: "\ud83d\ude04" is a surrogate pair, and is perfectly valid UTF-16 for U+1F604---which is all that `NSString` supports.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

Convert Emoji to unicode

```
NSData *data = [textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

goodValue = [goodValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
```

when fetch value from the server

```
NSString *goodValue = [StaticClass urlDecode:[dataDict objectForKey:@"comment_text"]];
NSData *newdata=[goodValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *mystring=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: i apply this solution but it return like \ud83d\ude04. I want result like 1F604 for SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES .

Answer (score 0):

// String to unicode

if let data = NormalString.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII), let convertedString = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        {
            return convertedString
        }

//Unicode to string

if let data = UnicodeString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), let convertedString = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
        {
            return convertedString
        }